# Каким боком подключить один файл js в другой?

Tags: javascript, anime.js

Начал с недавнего времени работать с библиотеки `anime.js`, но я не хочу засорять код html поэтому хочу созать файл `mine.js` подключить туда `anime.min.js` и потом в html просто подключить файл:

```
<script src ="mine.js"><script>
```

пробовал:

```
function include(url) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = url;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

не получилось, пробовал через `jQuery` - не работает, помогите!

Comment: Скрипты загружаются по порядку, просто подключите anime.min.js выше mine.js в файле html.

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так ответ я нашел сам, спасибо всем но ответ который я выбрал рабатал не так как я хотел, решение такое, в конце тега  мы подключаем библиотеку, и потом наш скрипт файл, вот как это выглядит

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>TEST STACK OVE FLOW RU</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <h2>Что то</h2>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Ваш скрипт"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Библиотека"></script>>
</body>
</html>
```

еще раз повторяю обязательно в низ тега body !

Answer (score 1):

```
$.getScript('/assets/js/' + item + '.js', function () {
            window[String(nameFunc)](param);
        });
```

item - имя скрипта который будет подключен

nameFunc - имя функции которая будет вызвана

param - передача параметра в функцию

**должен быть подключен jquery!!**

Answer (score -1):

`Html` как раз таки "создан" для содержания в себе библиотек.

Ты можешь просто собрать содержимое файлов библиотек в один `.js` файл, затем подключить *только один файл*, в нём также может содержаться твой код

Либо, ты хотел что-то такое:

```js
$('body').append(`<script src="https://SITE.com/LIBRARY.min.js"></script>`);
```

Ибо не совсем понятно, что ты хочешь